# Save an imagemagick blob to a node buffer

Tags: c++, node.js, segmentation-fault, node.js-addon, magick++

I am writing an imagemagick extension for node, and when I try to save the blob to the buffer, I get **Segmentation fault**.

```
using Magick::Blob;
using v8::MaybeLocal;
using v8::Object;

Isolate *isolate = args.GetIsolate();
NodeMagick *obj = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<NodeMagick>(args.Holder());

Blob blob;
obj->image.write(&blob);
MaybeLocal<Object> buffer = node::Buffer::New(isolate, (char *)blob.data(), node::encoding::UTF8);
```

If I print out the Blob, I get some data back, not everything though...

```
printf((char*)blob.data());
// Displays:
// ëPNG
```

I am not exactly sure why this is happening. Is my data not getting fully saved to the blob?

If I change `obj->image.write(&blob);` to `obj->image.write("out.png");` and remove the `buffer = ...` the file gets created and is viewable, so what am I missing here with the Blob?

Comment: `printf` will not show all your data because it stops at a NUL byte. It's designed for text data not the binary data that you have.

Comment: Time to fire up your debugger.

Comment: Also for binary data `node::encoding::UTF8` seems wrong. PNG files are not UTF-8 encoded. That could easily be the cause of your crash (but I'm only guessing).

Comment: I have also tried using `node::encoding::BINARY`, and `blob.length()` in place of the encoding, that also gives a segment fault...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn According to [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_buffer.h) the third parameter to `node::Buffer::New` is a length not an encoding. You need to do better than guess at the API you are using.

Comment: To me, it shows both an encoding or a length... This is also my first c++ program, so I don't know the language super well yet.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you need to tell Node's `Buffer` how large the blob size is.

```cpp
 Blob blob;
 obj->image.write(&blob)
 MaybeLocal<Object> buffer = node::Buffer::Copy(isolate,
                                                (char *)blob.data(),
                                                blob.length());
```

Looking at the [`node_buffer.h`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_buffer.h#L48) file, it may be more appropriate to use the `node::Buffer::Copy` constructor, or risk additional faults during deallocation.

Comment: I tried using `blob.length()` which also gave the same issue. I am trying to use `copy` as you mentioned, and that so far has been working....